# An $A$-module M is isomorphic to an A-module of the form $A/m$ for some maximal ideal m of A $\Longrightarrow$ M is a simple $A-$module

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have to show:

An $A$-module M is isomorphic to an A-module of the form $A/m$ for some maximal ideal m of A $\Longleftrightarrow$ M is a simple $A$-module

I have already proved this direction $'\Longleftarrow '$, but now I have trouble
showing the other side.
I tried doing it with a contraposition, saying $m$ is not maximal and hence there exists an ideal $m \subsetneq I \subsetneq M$ and there is an isomorphism $f: A/m \to M$. Then $0 \subsetneq f(A/m) \subsetneq M$ is a submodule of $M$, so $M$ is not simple. This feels wrong, was it wrong to state that $f$ exists in my contraposition? Can somebody help me?

Comment: In this direction you just have to show that $A/m$ is a simple module. And this immediately follows from the correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A/m$ is simple because the $A$-submodules of $A/m$ correspond exactly to the ideals of $A$ containing $m$. But since $m$ is maximal the only such ideal is $m$ itself. Hence, the only submodules of $A/m$ are $0,A/m$ which by definition means that $A/m$ is simple. It may be worth pointing out that $A/m\neq 0$ because $m\subset A\setminus A^\times$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: But can you explain what you mean by  $A^x$ ?

Comment: $A^\times$ are the units of $A$. It's just saying that a maximal ideal can't contain any units because otherwise it would be equal to $A$, but maximal ideals are always proper ideals of $A$.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much!